# using one html page's dropdown list to another html page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a main html5 page (`main.html`) and two another html5 pages(`country.html` and `state.html`).

`country.html` page contains a select dropdown list of 250 countries like below.

```
<select>
   <option value="1">Afghanistan</option>
   <option value="2">Albania</option>
   .....
   <option value="1">Canary Islands</option>
</select>
```

`state.html` contains select dropdown list of states of 250 countries like below

```
<select id="1">
     <option value="1">Badakhshan</option>
     <option value="1">Badghis</option>
     ............
     <option value="32">Zabol</option>
</select>

<select id="2">
     <option value="33">Badakhshan</option>
     <option value="34">Badghis</option>
     ............
     <option value="68">Vlore</option>
</select>

...............
<select id="250">
     <option value="4902">Saba</option>
     <option value="4903">Sint Eustatius</option>
     ............
     <option value="4915">Western Equatoria</option>
</select>
```

I have to show dropdown list of all countries in `main.html` and another dropdown list of all states of selected country from country dropdown list. `main.html` is like below

```
<select id="country">
  like to add from country.html
</select>

<select id="state>
  like to add from state.html
</select>
```

Since it is necessary to show country and state dropdown list more than 5 times so i like to use `country.html` and `state.html`. How can i do that? Any help or clue is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can be done in both client side and server side. Doing it in server side is less complex than doing it in client side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

main.html

```
<div id="countries"></div>
<div id="states"></div>
```

jQuery script

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // load select code from country.html
    $('#countries').load('country.html select', function() {
        // when country is selected
        $('#countries select').change(function() {
            // get id
            var countryId = $(this).children('option:selected').val();
            // load select code from state.html by id
            $('#states').load('state.html #'+countryId, function() {
                $('#states select').change(function() {
                    // use the same method to get state id
                    var stateId = $(this).children('option:selected').val();
                });
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you, it is showing properly but i need to take the value of both dropdown lists to insert database. How can i take the value?

Comment: how can i get the id of state. here you show how to catch id of country.

Comment: Thank you very much. it is working though i solved it before you sent

Answer (score 0):

You can also try for this solution:-

You can make both drop-down html into a java-script function on a `java-script file(.js)` and Call this java-script file function on page load(`$(document).ready();`).

Example - 
Make a java-script file `Demo.js` -

```
function MakeDropDown() {
     var DropDownHtml = "";
     DropDownHtml = "<select><option value='1'>Afghanistan</option><option value='2'>Albania</option><option value='1'>Canary Islands</option></select>";
     return DropDownHtml;    
  }
```

Set refrence of Demo.js on Your pages -

```
<script src="Demo.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Call MakeDropDown() function on pageload -

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  alert(MakeDropDown());
  $('#PageDropdown').html(MakeDropDown());
});
```

Drop-down Html -

```
<select id="PageDropdown"></select>
```